# The following classes could not be found: - ImageButton (Change to android.widget.ImageButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Tags: java, android

The following classes could not be found:
 - `ImageButton` (Change to `android.widget.ImageButton`, `Fix Build Path`, `Edit XML`)

This happens when i use `android:src="@drawable/change_button"` to point to the selector xml file to define the button's state when the button is press or not press!

Comment: Where does that happen? At runtime, in the visual layout editor? In the XML editor? How does your ImageButton tag in your layout XML file look like?

Comment: Is it works fine if you use an image instead of selector xml file?

Answer (score 0):

*"This happens when i use android:src="@drawable/change_button"*

The image on the surface of the button is defined either by the `android:src` attribute in the XML element or by the `setImageResource(int)` method.

So, try second method. If error persists, Checkout your *change_button.xml*